# Creating SSIS packages locally over Vnet

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, mariadb, azure-data-factory, vnet

Firs of all I would like to prepare the reader that I'm totally new to SSIS and also the parts that will be mentioned below regarding Azure.

**The scenario** I have is a task in building SSIS packages to transfer data from a MariaDB to an Azure SQL DB. The MariaDB is located in another external environment that we have a connection and access to through a vnet that we have set up in Azure.
With the connection established we have created an SSIS-DB that should be able to 
run the ssis packages with the help of an Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime in Data Factory.

**The question** I have is regarding to be able to build the ssis packages from visual studio on my computer. 
How do I establish a connection when building the data flows to the source db (maria-db) over the vnet in Azure when trying do build data-flows and ETL jobs locally in visual studio?

Comment: Hi @john why don't you use the the Azure DataFactory Designer instead?

Comment: @Arthur you mean I can build the ssis packages in a designer view so to speak?

Comment: that's what I see being implied from your inquest

Comment: Well i don't know if its the right name of the technology but are you talking about the "Author" technology where you can create pipelines? If thats it i cant use it as i need to install the "Microsoft integration runtime" to be able to connect to the database. And as the MariaDB on the external side of this solution is created on a "non-microsoft" environment i cant install it. Thus i cant connect to the Maria DB in the "designer"...